# Check for conditional first occurrence in a dataframe values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a sample dataframe(df) like below:

```
              Date_Time      Open      High       Low     Close   UOD  VWB
20  2020-07-01 10:30:00  10298.85  10299.90  10287.85  10299.90    UP    3
21  2020-07-01 10:35:00  10301.40  10310.00  10299.15  10305.75    UP    3
22  2020-07-01 10:40:00  10305.75  10305.75  10285.50  10290.00  DOWN    3
24  2020-07-01 10:45:00  10290.00  10291.20  10277.65  10282.65  DOWN    0
25  2020-07-01 10:50:00  10282.30  10289.80  10278.00  10282.00  DOWN    3
26  2020-07-01 10:55:00  10280.10  10295.00  10279.80  10291.50    UP    3
27  2020-07-01 11:00:00  10290.00  10299.95  10287.30  10297.55    UP    3
28  2020-07-01 11:05:00  10296.70  10306.30  10294.50  10299.40    UP    3
29  2020-07-01 11:10:00  10299.95  10301.10  10291.50  10292.00  DOWN    0
30  2020-07-01 11:15:00  10293.05  10298.70  10286.00  10291.55  DOWN    3
31  2020-07-01 11:20:00  10292.00  10298.70  10286.00  10351.45  DOWN    1
```

I have below conditions:

> 1. Check for df['VWB'] == 0 & df['UOD'] == "DOWN" & get the corresponding **Open** value (= 10290.00 in my example)
> 2. Then Find the first occurrence of **Close** value greater than this **Open** value (10290.00) after that row.

I want my desired outout as below with Valid Column

```
              Date_Time      Open      High       Low     Close   UOD  VWB  Valid
20  2020-07-01 10:30:00  10298.85  10299.90  10287.85  10299.90    UP    3      0
21  2020-07-01 10:35:00  10301.40  10310.00  10299.15  10305.75    UP    3      0
22  2020-07-01 10:40:00  10305.75  10305.75  10285.50  10290.00  DOWN    3      0
23  2020-07-01 10:45:00  10290.00  10291.20  10277.65  10282.65  DOWN    0      0
25  2020-07-01 10:50:00  10282.30  10289.80  10278.00  10282.00  DOWN    3      0
26  2020-07-01 10:55:00  10280.10  10295.00  10279.80  10291.50    UP    3      1 <<= first occurrence
27  2020-07-01 11:00:00  10290.00  10299.95  10287.30  10297.55    UP    3      0
28  2020-07-01 11:05:00  10296.70  10306.30  10294.50  10299.40    UP    3      0
29  2020-07-01 11:10:00  10299.95  10301.10  10291.50  10292.00  DOWN    0      0
30  2020-07-01 11:15:00  10293.05  10298.70  10286.00  10291.55  DOWN    3      0
31  2020-07-01 11:20:00  10292.00  10298.70  10286.00  10351.45  DOWN    1      1 <<= first occurrence
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little tricky as I assume it's possible to have multiple values with the following bool.

```
df.loc[(df["VWB"] == 0) & (df["UOD"] == "DOWN")]
```

We can create a psuedo key to capture each group with a vectorised operation.

I've edited your sample so we have 2 values that can equate to True for the above boolean.

```
print(df)

            Date_Time      Open      High       Low     Close   UOD  VWB
0 2020-07-01 10:30:00  10298.85  10299.90  10287.85  10299.90    UP    3
1 2020-07-01 10:35:00  10301.40  10310.00  10299.15  10305.75    UP    3
2 2020-07-01 10:40:00  10305.75  10305.75  10285.50  10290.00  DOWN    3
3 2020-07-01 10:45:00  10290.00  10291.20  10277.65  10282.65  DOWN    0
4 2020-07-01 10:50:00  10282.30  10289.80  10278.00  10282.00  DOWN    3
5 2020-07-01 10:55:00  10280.10  10295.00  10279.80  10291.50    UP    3
6 2020-07-01 11:00:00  10290.00  10299.95  10287.30  10297.55    UP    3
7 2020-07-01 11:05:00  10296.70  10306.30  10294.50  10299.40    UP    3
8 2020-07-01 11:10:00  10299.95  10301.10  10291.50  10292.00  DOWN    0
9 2020-07-01 11:15:00  10293.05  10298.70  10286.00  10595.55  DOWN    3
```

---

```
s = df.loc[(df["VWB"] == 0) & (df["UOD"] == "DOWN"), "Open"]

df1 = df.assign(key=df.index.isin(s.index).cumsum())
# we will filter out the 0 key.


print(df1)

            Date_Time      Open      High       Low     Close   UOD  VWB  key
0 2020-07-01 10:30:00  10298.85  10299.90  10287.85  10299.90    UP    3    0
1 2020-07-01 10:35:00  10301.40  10310.00  10299.15  10305.75    UP    3    0
2 2020-07-01 10:40:00  10305.75  10305.75  10285.50  10290.00  DOWN    3    0
3 2020-07-01 10:45:00  10290.00  10291.20  10277.65  10282.65  DOWN    0    1
4 2020-07-01 10:50:00  10282.30  10289.80  10278.00  10282.00  DOWN    3    1
5 2020-07-01 10:55:00  10280.10  10295.00  10279.80  10291.50    UP    3    1
6 2020-07-01 11:00:00  10290.00  10299.95  10287.30  10297.55    UP    3    1
7 2020-07-01 11:05:00  10296.70  10306.30  10294.50  10299.40    UP    3    1
8 2020-07-01 11:10:00  10299.95  10301.10  10291.50  10292.00  DOWN    0    2
9 2020-07-01 11:15:00  10293.05  10298.70  10286.00  10595.55  DOWN    3    2
```

---

now for each group we need to compare the first instance of `Open` and see where `Close` is greater.

```
idx = df1.assign(tempOpen=df1.groupby("key")["Open"].transform("first")).query(
    "Close > tempOpen"
).groupby("key", as_index=False)["key"].idxmin()


df['valid'] = np.where(df1.index.isin(idx) & df1.key.ne(0),1,0)

print(df[['Open','Close','valid']])

       Open     Close  valid
0  10298.85  10299.90      0
1  10301.40  10305.75      0
2  10305.75  10290.00      0
3  10290.00  10282.65      0
4  10282.30  10282.00      0
5  10280.10  10291.50      1
6  10290.00  10297.55      0
7  10296.70  10299.40      0
8  10299.95  10292.00      0
9  10293.05  10595.55      1
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. Nice answer.

Comment: Sir, how to calculate the time difference (in sec) between Condition 1 and first occurrence (in my case 2020-07-01 10:45:00  minus 2020-07-01 10:55:00 = 600 Second)

Comment: Sir, I have created a new question. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037503/calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-rows-with-condition-in-a-dataframe

Comment: Sir, I am still waiting for your answer. Your answer was silky here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['Val'] = 0
# 1st condition
open_val = df.loc[(df['VWB'].eq(0)) & (df['UOD'].eq("DOWN"))]['Open'].values[0]
u = df.loc[(df['Close'] > open_val)]
# 2nd condition
pos = u.iloc[(u['Close'] - open_val).argsort()[0]]

df.loc[pos,'Val'] = 1
```

---

```
             Date_Time      Open      High       Low     Close   UOD  VWB  Val
20 2020-07-01 10:30:00  10298.85  10299.90  10287.85  10299.90    UP    3    0
21 2020-07-01 10:35:00  10301.40  10310.00  10299.15  10305.75    UP    3    0
22 2020-07-01 10:40:00  10305.75  10305.75  10285.50  10290.00  DOWN    3    0
24 2020-07-01 10:45:00  10290.00  10291.20  10277.65  10282.65  DOWN    0    0
25 2020-07-01 10:50:00  10282.30  10289.80  10278.00  10282.00  DOWN    3    0
26 2020-07-01 10:55:00  10280.10  10295.00  10279.80  10291.50    UP    3    1
27 2020-07-01 11:00:00  10290.00  10299.95  10287.30  10297.55    UP    3    0
28 2020-07-01 11:05:00  10296.70  10306.30  10294.50  10299.40    UP    3    0
29 2020-07-01 11:10:00  10299.95  10301.10  10291.50  10292.00  DOWN    3    0
30 2020-07-01 11:15:00  10293.05  10298.70  10286.00  10291.55  DOWN    3    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach using `apply`:

```
def valid_column(df):
    max_val = max(df['Open']) + 1
    min_open = max_val

    def find_valid(row):
        global min_open
        if min_open < max_val and row['Close'] > min_open:
            min_open = max_val
            return 1
        if row['VWB'] == 0 and row['UOD'] == "DOWN":
            min_open = min(min_open, row['Open'])
        return 0

    return df.apply(find_valid, axis=1)

df['Valid'] = valid_column(df)
```

You only go through the dataset once, and using the `apply` function which is very efficient.

The `min_open` variable keeps track of the lowest "Open" value. If any row has a "Close" value bigger, then a 1 is returned and `min_open` is reset.

Note that one drawback of this approach, is the use of the `global` keyword which means you cannot have another variable in you code with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

One small nit to Umar's good answer is that numpy wants parenthesis surrounding multiple conditionals:

```
df['valid'] = np.where(df1.index.isin(idx) & df1.key.ne(0),1,0)

// should be:

df['valid'] = np.where((df1.index.isin(idx['key'])) & (df1.key.ne(0)), 1, 0)
```